# HTML checkbox in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, checkbox

I have two radio buttons based on which I want to show a list of checkboxes to the user. But the problem is that when user checks any checkbox in the first list, it automatically checks the boxes in the second list too.

Here are my radio buttons:

```
<input 
checked={optionLocal==='residential' ? 'checked' : ''}                                  
onClick={()=>{
setOptionLocal('residential')
}} 
type="radio" 
id="residential" 
name="option" 
value="residential"/>

<input 
checked={optionLocal==='commercial' ? 'checked' : ''} 
onClick={()=>{
setOptionLocal('commercial')
}} 
type="radio" 
id="commercial" 
name="option" 
value="commercial"/>
```

When I click one of them, it stores the state locally and based on that list is generated.

```
optionLocal === 'residential' ? (
                            residential.map((row,index)=>{
                                return(
                                    <li>
                                        <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-baseline px-3">
                                            <input 
                                            type="checkbox" 
                                            id={'r-' + row} 
                                            name={'r-' + row} 
                                            value={'r-' + row}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })
                        ) : (
                            commercial.map((row,index)=>{
                                return(
                                    <li>
                                        <div className="d-flex flex-row align-items-baseline px-3">
                                            <input 
                                            type="checkbox" 
                                            id={'c-' + row} 
                                            name={'c-' + row} 
                                            value={'c-' + row}/>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })
                        )
```

Here is what is happening.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Please Share your `useState` details!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the same state property for both lists. You can either store two different properties for the selected items in each list or clean the state when you select a different option in the radio buttons

Bonus hint: When you use `map` and return a JSX element, you should set the `key` property on the element returned, in this case: `li`. It will help not rendering all the list every time the state changes because the list is the same.